# Event doesn't seem to hook up properly

Tags: c#, events, mvvm

I have an abstract base class with a public Event PropertyChanged. I have a child class composed of another child class, and I want to propogate the event to the owner. But when I try to hook up the event I get nothing.

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged == null) return;

        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Customer : ViewModel
{
   public Address Address
    {
        get { return _Address; }
        set
        {
            _Address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }
    private Address _Address = new Address();

    public Customer()
    {
        // I get nothing here. But why?
        Address.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => Logger.Log("Just do something, please!");

        // What I want to do is get Customer propertychange to fire
        // Because currently Address changes are not detected.
    }
}

public class Address : ViewModel
{
    private string _addy = "";
    public string Addy
    {
        get { return _addy; }
        set 
        {
            _addy=value;
            Logger.Log("Testing that at least something works");
            // I have verified that this is getting called, firing the event.
            OnPropertyChange("Addy");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: UPDATE:

For those who are curious (I think that's you, Servy). The issue turned out to be Address was getting reset in another part of the code. So in fact the hook up was occurring as expected in the constructor, and then immediately lost because Address was set to a different instance.

I appreciate the responses. It helped me narrow down what the problem *wasn't* (it wasn't a syntax error). It also helped me understand how to post better questions in the future. By posting the question in a difficult situation, I was able to track down a simple yet elusive answer. Thank you. Your contributions were very helpful.

However, I would argue this question *demonstrated the specific problem*, and that the question was and continues to be updated to meet any concerns about compilability (the code above works just fine). With regards to the code two things. 1. I have updated it each time someone had a concern. 2. I have used this site plenty of times and been benefited by those who could actually tell the difference between a conceptual problem like this one that only requires pseudo code to demonstrate. So I was unaware that using pseudo code would cause such a ruckus. Sincere apologies. I will be more careful in the future.

I argue this question *demonstrated the specific problem* because my specific problem was I could not figure out why the event was not hooking up although it was firing. The problem was narrowed by Servy (it isn't a syntax error) solved exactly by Wonko (the logic was flawed because Address was getting overwritten), but I am open to learning more about what is appropriate for stack overflow and what isn't.

At this point I would be more than happy to have this topic closed since it seems to be such a problem for some people. But I don't know how to close it. Once I realized it was such a big deal to some, I tried deleting it, but you can't delete topics with comments :(

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in the code so that it actually *compiles* first.  There are quite a few actually.

Comment: When I fix the syntax errors and ensure that an `Address` is constructed in the `Customer` constructor it works just fine, as I would have thought.

Comment: @nuke There are several, actually.  There's that, and the fact that `Address` has a member of the same name as it's type, and `class` was missing from all class definitions (now edited), an `Address` isn't constructed for each customer when the event is added, resulting in a NRE, and `_addy` is accessed as `addy` (missing underscore).

Comment: I updated the errors. Address is not null in the constructor. Understand I simplified the sample above to show my basic structure. The syntax is not my problem, but the fact that the event doesn't seem to work. But I get nothing.

Comment: You can't get anything because it does not even compile as Servy told you. When you have fixed all compiler errors please press F5 and read [Debuging Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx) to find the logical errors.

Comment: `Address` most certainly *is* null in the constructor, at least in the code you have here.

Comment: It isn't a logical error. The event isn't hooking up. Nothing happens as expected.

Comment: @PriceJones now that you've finally fixed all of the compiler error the only problem left is that `Address` is *still* null in the `Customer` constructor, and it throws a NRE on the event subscription.  If you construct a new address before then then it works just fine.

Comment: @Servy If you actually read my comments and looked at my code you would see the very important comment //this implements inpc but I don't show that here. Ergo the Address is not null.

Comment: @PriceJones Then you need to *provide code that demonstrates the problem*.  You *still* haven't done that.  The code that you have *actually* shown doesn't demonstrate the problem that you have.  You'll need to adjust your example code to ensure that it also has the same problem as your real code or else it's useless.  IF you have a problem clearly it's in the code that you didn't bother to show us, so we can't help you.  When you eventually provide a code sample that has the problem you're describing we'll actually be able to help.

Comment: @Servy the code *does* demonstrate my problem. But you have it in your head that it doesn't. I can't help you help me with a problem you can't detect. The code is what is and you and wonko can get it to work, but I can't. So at least you have help me narrow down what it isn't - which is a syntax error. Thank you. But I still have to find a solution. It could be in visual studio. I will keep looking.

Comment: @PriceJones I'm running the code.  When I fix the bug that you have in your example code it works just fine.  I've run it several times now.  Clearly your problem is with code you haven't shown us.  *The code that you have shown* does not demonstrate the problem.  The fact that you have code that you haven't shown with a problem doesn't help us.  Without knowing what it is, we can't know what about it you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minor modifications so that your code compiles everything works fine for me:

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {          
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.Address.Address1 = "HAllo";
        }

        public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged == null) return;

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }   
        }

        public class Customer : ViewModel
        {
            public Address Address { get; set; } //this implements inpc but I don't show that here.
            public Customer()
            {
                Address = new Address();
                // I get nothing here. But why?
                Address.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Just do something, please!");

                // What I want to do is get Customer propertychange to fire
                // Because currently Address changes are not detected.
            }
        }

        public class Address : ViewModel
        {
            private string _addy = "";
            public string Address1
            {
                get { return _addy; }
                set
                {
                    _addy = value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Testing that at least something works");
                    // I have verified that this is getting called, firing the event.
                    OnPropertyChange("Addy");
                }
            }
        }
```

Please take my advice above to read something about [debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx) serious.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want your customer class to fire OnPropertyChanged event whenever its Address fires the event. If so, you need to change the subscription in the customer class to thefollowing:

```
public Customer : ViewModel
{
    public Address Address {get; set;} //this implements inpc but I don't show that here.
    public Customer()
    {
        // I get nothing here. But why?
        Address.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => OnPropertyChange(e.PropertyName);

        // What I want to do is get Customer propertychange to fire
        // Because currently Address changes are not detected.
    }
}
```

What you are basically doing is replaying the event fire

Comment: But if his existing event handler isn't logging then this change wouldn't matter.  The point of just logging is to simplify the example code and show that it's failing *before it even gets to this point*.

Comment: So you are not even reaching the  Address.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => Log.....? Can you show the code which modifies the address property of customer?

Comment: It's not my question, but the OP is indicating that the `Address.PropertyChanged` handler is not being executed; the log entry isn't there.

Comment: I edited the code to show the implementation of Address in Customer.

Comment: @Servy, the question indicates that Address.PropertyChanged IS being executed, but the delegate from Customer is NOT, even though I have attached it properly. So there is some reason why the hookup is not occurring, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Now it is clear now, you want the event firing whenever you change the Adress object itself, not adresses properties. So to do that chacge the subscrtiption to the following "this.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => Logger.Log("Just do something, please!");"

Comment: This should work as the propery changes on the Customer class, so you need to subscribe to itself for the property change event

Comment: Did it actually worked?